# Moving Div within window using arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrow-keys

I'm new to coding and trying to make a game were I move my div along the x and y axis. When I run code I get an error in the marginLeft variable as well as the marginTop. I included these variables because I want successive keydown strokes to continue to move div. I would like to code using only jquery if possible.

```js
var player = $('#player');
var marginleft = $('#player').offset().left;
var margintop = $('#player').offset().top;


function movePlayer(e) {
  if (e.keydown==39) {
    marginleft +=2;
    player.css('left', marginleft + 'px');
  }
  if (e.keydown==37) {
    marginleft -=2;
    player.css('left', marginleft + 'px');
  }
  if (e.keydown==40) {
    margintop +=2;
    player.css('top', margintop + 'px');
  }
  if (e.keydown==38) {
    margintop -=2;
    player.css('top', margintop + 'px');
  }
}
```

```css
#player {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="player"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you forgot to include the code that listens for key press in your example. we can't test it w/o that

Comment: Please provide the code that @CoryDanielson suggested. Also you want to take a look at canvas, more flexible imo

Answer (score 1):

Your code worked fine when I modified it to use `e.which` in the event listeners. I also attached the event listener in the bottom of the snippit.

Click inside the game before using the arrow keys: https://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/kchrv4t4/

```
var player = $('#player');
var marginleft = $('#player').offset().left;
var margintop = $('#player').offset().top;

function movePlayer(e) {
  if (e.which==39) {
    marginleft +=2;
    player.css('left', marginleft + 'px');
  }
  if (e.which==37) {
    marginleft -=2;
    player.css('left', marginleft + 'px');
  }
  if (e.which==40) {
    margintop +=2;
    player.css('top', margintop + 'px');
  }
  if (e.which==38) {
    margintop -=2;
    player.css('top', margintop + 'px');
  }
}

$(document.body).on('keydown', movePlayer);
```

You should use `e.which` when using jQuery. There's a lot of discrepancies between browsers and key codes. `which` is the safe way to determine keycodes. https://api.jquery.com/event.which/

Answer (score 0):

> When I run code I get an error in the marginLeft variable as well as the marginTop

This phare let me think you are defining and initializing the variables outside the document ready...

If you need to move your div only inside visible document area a solutioon can be:

```js
//
// declare global variables and functions outside the
//  document ready
//
var player;
var marginleft;
var margintop;
var docWidth;
var docHeight;

function movePlayer(e) {
  if (e.which==39) {
    if (marginleft >= docWidth) {
      return;
    }
    marginleft +=2;
    player.css('left', marginleft + 'px');
  }
  if (e.v==37) {
    if (marginleft<=0) {
      return;
    }
    marginleft -=2;
    player.css('left', marginleft + 'px');
  }
  if (e.which==40) {
    if (margintop >= docHeight) {
      return;
    }
    margintop +=2;
    player.css('top', margintop + 'px');
  }
  if (e.which==38) {
    if (margintop<=0) {
      return;
    }
    margintop -=2;
    player.css('top', margintop + 'px');
  }
}

//
// On document ready: set the variables and
// add the event listener for keydown event
//
$(function () {
  player = $('#player');
  marginleft = $('#player').offset().left;
  margintop = $('#player').offset().top;
  docWidth = $(document).width() - player.width();
  docHeight = $(document).height() - player.height();

  $(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    movePlayer(e);
  });
});
```

```css
#player {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="player"></div>
```